# Name/class of application that can track Windows usage over time

Tags: windows, resource-usage

We often get users complaining about slow laptops so I'm looking to investigate applications that can monitor a computer over a period of time and then produce some easy to understand reports.

Problem is that I don't even know what this type of application is called to then stick into Google. I'm not looking for recommendations as I know that's a no-no here.

All my searches so far bring up pages on using system tray apps or Windows Resource monitor whereas I want something that can be left running for a week and then the reports digested.

Comment: Try one of the Event Viewer log apps:  https://www.datadoghq.com/ts/logs/log-analysis/?utm_source=Advertisement&utm_medium=GoogleAdsLogs&utm_campaign=GoogleAdsLogs-LogAnalysisTshirt&utm_content=Logs&utm_keyword=%2Blog%20%2Banalysis&utm_matchtype=b&gclid=Cj0KCQjwh_eFBhDZARIsALHjIKfIdoSccV7TIuUvewqtUxYgWMpx0OTKPhPMqYL5wXao_Mw6OerCS8EaAkVPEALw_wcB

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Microsofts Sysinternals sysmon utility. It will give you really detailed information about what's happening.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.